# Matrix multiplication with openMP and MPI

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp

I am trying turn this code snippet into an OpenMP version and a MPI version

```
int A[100000];
int B[100000];
int C=0;

for int(i=0; i < 100000; i++)
C += A[i] * B[i];
```

In order to make an OpenMP I need to parallelize the for loop:

```
int A[100000];
int B[100000];
int C=0;

#pragma omp parallel for
for int(i=0; i < 100000; i++)
C += A[i] * B[i];
```

I am not sure with the MPI version, but I will give it a shot. First I need to scatter the matrix A, then broadcast matrix B and lastly I need to use gather for C as:

```
int A[100000];
int B[100000];
int C=0;

MPI_Scatter(A,count...);
MPI_Scatter(B,count...);             
MPI_Gather(C,count...);
```

Are the they correct?

Comment: The snippet is for a dot product (e.g. two vectors) and not a matrix multiplication (!). For a dot product, you can `MPI_Scatter()` both vectors, compute the partial dot product, and then `MPI_Reduce(..., op=MPI_SUM, ...)`

Comment: Don't forget to eliminate the data race in the OpenMP version.